# Are namespaces are clusterwide objects?

Tags: kubernetes, k8s-rolebinding, k8s-cluster-role

Can I a list all the namespaces using a role and not a clusterrole resource? If yes, can anyone help me with some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are cluster-wide objects.

The only way to access them is if there exists a ClusterRoleBinding and a corresponding ClusterRole that gives your principal (user, service account,etc) permissions to list namespaces.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, but I have a use case to use only role and rolebindings to list all the namespaces. Anyway to achieve or any workarounds as this is a multi-tenancy cluster only